# non bookmarkable secure download link

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web

I need to implement a non bookmarkable, secure download link:

1. I'd like to ensure that the form post is made from a genuine link from my site.
2. the link is only valid for 5 mins for 1 click only

I'm planning to do it by:

1. link should render with a access-token that's only valid for 5 mins and for 1 single download
2. clicking on the link will submit an HTTP POST to the download endpoint with the access token. HTTP POST download endpoint over https will be implemented using Asp.Net MVC 3)
3. upon a valid http post request (ntlm authentication token, valid http referer, etc.) returns a pdf file (content-disposition: attachment; ... pdf and mime-type: application/pdf).
4. link and download endpoint are hosted in two different web apps
5. second http post request will return an HTTP 401

Before rolling out my own custom request ticket solution across the 2 web apps, I wonder if there's a open source or 3rd party library that does exactly this. Thoughts?

Thanks
Ron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any projects that satisfied the above requirements. However, the closest that I could find is if I were to use Windows Azure blob storage I'll be able to use [Access Control List feature which gives me an option to set a start/expiry date to a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179391.aspx)